# can I Use Azure Service Bus to secure REST calls from my APP?

Tags: service, servicebus

How could Azure help me to secure my rest services? Does the Service Bus provide a easier way to secure my REST services without requiring me in install my own SSL certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. ServiceBus uses SSL to encrypt the connection at the transport level, and ACS for authentication and authorization. You don't need to import your own certificate for this scenario.

Here's an example of how to use the SB REST APIs with ACS enabled:
http://rickgaribay.net/archive/2012/01/19/common-service-bus-queue-operations-with-the-rest-api.aspx